# Unwanted vertical scroll on some viewports with parent div element after body tag

Tags: scroll, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I worked on a practice project yesterday for a login and sign-up website and up till this morning I have battled with a Vertical scroll in all the pages on some viewports when in fact, all the elements should be fit on the screen across all devices. I tried Ai to get assistance but it still didn't work so I guessed it's not getting exactly what I meant to address. I would appreciate any help here in debugging the issue with the Vertical scroll which I suspect is coming from the parent div right after the body element based on what I saw in the developer tools section on my browser. Here's the link to the git-hub repo. Thanks in anticipation.

Ps: The site is getting flagged as a dangerous site because its about a login ang sign up but its actually harmless and doesn't even use real data from users or do anything with the data. The whole scripts and be checked on console for verification

https://github.com/Omoefe-bazunu/loginSignupSystem.git

I tried using overflow hidden for the y axis and expected that it stopped the vertical scroll but didn't work. Also tried using min-height but didn't solve it either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

**Inspect in Developer Tools:**

Open your website in a web browser, right-click on the page, and select "Inspect" (or use Ctrl+Shift+I or Cmd+Opt+I on macOS). Check the "Elements" tab to inspect the HTML structure, paying attention to the parent div you suspect is causing the vertical scroll.

**Check CSS Styles:**

Examine the styles applied to the parent div and its children. Look for properties like height, min-height, and overflow. Ensure that the parent div and its children are set up to fit within the desired viewport without causing a vertical scrollbar.

**Debugging CSS:**
Use the browser's developer tools to experiment with CSS changes in real-time. You can modify styles, such as setting overflow: hidden; or adjusting heights, to see their immediate effects. This helps in identifying the problematic CSS rules.

**Check for Overflowing Content:**
Make sure none of your content is causing an overflow. This could be due to large images, long text, or other elements that exceed the boundaries of their containers.

**Check for JavaScript Behavior:**
Inspect your JavaScript code to see if any scripts are dynamically modifying the height or content of the parent div. Events like resizing the window or loading content asynchronously may affect the layout.

**Viewport Meta Tag:**
Ensure that you have a properly configured viewport meta tag in the  of your HTML document. For example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This is crucial for responsive design and preventing unexpected scrolling on mobile devices.

**Cross-browser Compatibility:**
Test your website on multiple browsers to ensure that the issue is not browser-specific. Sometimes, certain CSS rules may behave differently across browsers.

Without direct access to your code, these are general recommendations to help you identify and fix the issue. If you encounter specific challenges during the debugging process or if you can provide more details about the code, feel free to ask for further assistance.

Comment: I tried those already but still couldn't figure it out. I will try it again and see if it will be a different outcome. Thanks. I appreciate